# I am trying to make a guess the word game but I get a logical error when it picks a random word that has two or more of the same letter

Tags: python

I have made a word guessing game but when it picks a random word with repeating letters in it, it works fine and puts the correctly guessed letters into a list. But how do I make it so it acknowledge that the random word has repeating letters so accepts repeating letters? For example, if the chosen word is ball and you entered s it would display that s is not in the word. If I entered l, it would say l is in the word and add it to a list called correct. If I then entered l again as ball has two l's, it will display that I have already entered that letter and will not let me continue any further. I don't know how I can make it acknowledge that the word has repeating letters. Here is the code:

````
words = ["burger","chips","ketchup","cake","crisp","coke","fruit"]
correct = []
guessed = []
print("Weclome to guess the word. Aim of the game is to guess all the letters in the word and then type what word you think the word is. The subject is food. You have 15 guesses")
j = random.choice(words)
x = len(j)
count = x
guesses = 15
print("The word is:", x , "letters long.")
while guesses > 0:
    guess1 = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    k = len(guess1)
    if k != 1:
        print("Not a valid guess!")
    if guess1 in j and guess1 in correct:
        print("You have already guessed this letter! Your number of guesses left is:", guesses)
    if guess1 in j and guess1 not in correct:
        print(guess1,"is in the word. You have:", guesses , "guesses left.")
        correct.append(guess1)
        guesses = guesses-1
        count = count-1
        print("You have", count ,"of", x , "letters left to guess and you correctly given these letters:", *correct)
    if guess1 not in j and guess1 not in guessed:
        guessed.append(guess1)
        print(guess1, "is not in the word. You have:", guesses , "guesses left and have given the following incorrect letters:", *guessed)
        guesses = guesses-1
    if guesses == 0:
        print("You have ran out of guesses!")
        break
    if count == 0:
        print("Well done! You have guessed all the letters. Now time to de-scramble them! You have unlimited guesses for the word.")
        print("These are the following letters you need to de-scramble")
        print(*correct)
        descramble = input("Enter what you think the word is: ").lower()
        if descramble == j:
            print("You guessed the word! Well done!")
            break
        if descramble != j:
            print(descramble,"is not the word.")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 import random
words = ["burger","chips","ketchup","cake","crisp","coke","fruit"]
correct = []
guessed = []
print("Weclome to guess the word. Aim of the game is to guess all the letters in the word and then type what word you think the word is. The subject is food. You have 15 guesses")
j = random.choice(words)
x = len(j)
count = x
guesses = 15
already_used_letters = list()
print("The word is:", x , "letters long.")
while guesses > 0:
    guess1 = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    k = len(guess1)
    if guess1 in already_used_letters:
        print("You already used this letter")
        guesses = guesses - 1
    already_used_letters.append(guess1)
    if k != 1:
        print("Not a valid guess!")
    if guess1 in j and guess1 in correct:
        print("You have already guessed this letter! Your number of guesses left is:", guesses)
    if guess1 in j and guess1 not in correct:
        print(guess1,"is in the word. You have:", guesses , "guesses left.")
        correct.append(guess1)
        guesses = guesses-1
        count = count-1
        print("You have", count ,"of", x , "letters left to guess and you correctly given these letters:", *correct)
    if guess1 not in j and guess1 not in guessed:
        guessed.append(guess1)
        print(guess1, "is not in the word. You have:", guesses , "guesses left and have given the following incorrect letters:", *guessed)
        guesses = guesses-1
    if guesses == 0:
        print("You have ran out of guesses!")
        break
    if count == 0:
        print("Well done! You have guessed all the letters. Now time to de-scramble them! You have unlimited guesses for the word.")
        print("These are the following letters you need to de-scramble")
        print(*correct)
        descramble = input("Enter what you think the word is: ").lower()
        if descramble == j:
            print("You guessed the word! Well done!")
            break
        if descramble != j:
            print(descramble,"is not the word.")
```

Comment: Ok thanks Anil but when I test this out, after every letter it says "You already used this letter." Thanks for your input but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Yeap you were right. I have edited it and can you try it. I need to add the letter to the list after if state, at the first I have added this letter before if and it always say " You already used this letter". Now it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

words = ["burger", "chips", "ketchup", "cake", "crisp", "coke", "fruit"]
correctLetters = []
wronglyGuessed = []
print(
    "Weclome to guess the word. Aim of the game is to guess all the letters in the word and then type what word you think the word is. The subject is food. You have 15 guesses")
word = random.choice(words)
# word = "aapplle"
lives = 15

while lives > 0:
    if len(word) == len(correctLetters):
        print(
            "Well done! You have guessed all the letters. Now time to de-scramble them! You have unlimited guesses for the word.")
        print("These are the following letters you need to de-scramble")
        print(*correctLetters)
        descramble = input("Enter what you think the word is: ").lower()
        if descramble == word:
            print("You guessed the word! Well done!")
            break
        else:
            print(descramble, "is not the word.")
            
    guess1 = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    if len(guess1) > 1 or not guess1.isalpha():
        print("Not a valid guess!")
        lives -= 1
        continue

    if guess1 in word:
        if word.count(guess1) > correctLetters.count(guess1):
            correctLetters.append(guess1)
            print("you found a letter")
        else:
            lives -= 1
            print('You guessed all the occurances')
        continue

    if guess1 not in word:
        lives -= 1
        print(f'Wrong guess. You have {lives} tries left')
        continue


if lives == 0:
    print("You ran out of guesses")
```

Your problem comes from here:

```
if guess1 in j and guess1 in correct:
        print("You have already guessed this letter! Your number of guesses left is:", guesses)
```

When you use `in` it will only find the first occurrence of said item and return true. In this case you are interested in also finding the case for duplicates and also keeping track of them. Thus, you need to take another approach: that of finding said duplicates and their number. I used a pre-built method `count()`.

I'd say there are a few more issues with your code:

- Use descriptive names for your variables. x, j, k, n can mean a lot of things whereas `guestNames` is pretty self explanatory
- When a case inside one of your `if`s was met and all following tests cannot evaluate true, just use a `continue` statement

Also, on a different note, i'd say that when a letter is guessed you assume all its occurances, but that's not programming related.

Comment: Ok thank you. The reason for my bad code is because I am 14, it is all self-taught. In school we learn about sorting methods and searching methods like binary, insertion and merge sorting.

Comment: If the random word was apple and I entered 3 p's not knowing what the word was, it says "You guessed all the letters.". Is there a way to stop it doing that?

Comment: Well, that seems correct to me. What is your expected behaviour? Do you mean that it should rather write to the console "You guessed all the occurrences of this letter" ? Think about some more possible issues with the code and reply here.